# Kivy App with ScreenManager Crashes because WindowSDL object has no attribute "Manager"?

Tags: python, navigation, kivy, screen

I'm building an app in Kivy and Python, and am in the process of adding navigation between my screens. Currently, the app crashes upon tapping on the Welcome page.

Here's the code structure of my ScreenManager, and the Screens:

```
class SwitchingScreenApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name="welcome"))
        sm.add_widget(SignupScreen(name="signup"))
        sm.add_widget(ThanksScreen(name="thanks"))
        sm.current = "welcome"
        return sm

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        welcomeLabel = Label(text='Welcome!',
            halign= 'center', font_size=32, color=(0,0,0,1))
        image = Image(source="logo.png", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=True)
        nextLabel = Label(text='Touch anywhere to proceed.',
            halign= 'center', font_size=24, color=(0,0,0,1))
        box.add_widget(welcomeLabel)
        box.add_widget(image)
        box.add_widget(nextLabel)
        self.add_widget(box)

    def callback(self):
        print('The button has been pressed')
        self.manager.current = 'signup'

SwitchingScreenApp().run()
```

Currently the app crashes when I touch the screen, due to

```
File "/home/pi/Terminal2/main.py", line 350, in on_motion
     self.manager.current = 'success'
 AttributeError: 'WindowSDL' object has no attribute 'manager'
```

I an not sure where else to look, as I've followed the architecture from the answer from this post: [python- Kivy Screen Manager within .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53386394/python-kivy-screen-manager-within-py-file)

What am I missing in my implementation?

Comment: Did you `bind` the `callback()` to `on_motion` somewhere? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Yes, forgot interpreted languages act like this.